# jump list gone after office update from 2010 to 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2013, jumplist, software-update

I recently updated from office 2010 to office 2013 and my jump list is gone for excel,word etc. I had saved the CustomDestinations and Automaticdestinations file. however this apparently does not help. Any suggestions to update or edit jumplists or any other way to restore my office 2010 jumplist on office 2013 applications, I have saved in a different place the old Custom and Auto destination files.

Answer (score 0):

Believe the program path changed so you get different AppID hash for use in Jump Lists. The old lists are no longer valid for the updated program.

Not sure if the data file allows it, but might be able to change the AppID of the old jump list file names from the AutomaticDestinations folder to be able to migrate from 2010 -> 2013

Here are some useful links...

List of Jump List IDs
http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/List_of_Jump_List_IDs

AppID hash calculator
http://www.hexacorn.com/blog/2013/04/30/jumplists-file-names-and-appid-calculator/

NirSoft's Jump List Viewer
https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/jump_lists_view.html